# ruby unicorn as service in docker - uses wrong rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rake, unicorn

my problem is that i can start unicorn as a service in docker, though it works just fine if i start it from command line.

trying to build ruby with unicorn and nginx web server docker image.
using as a base `FROM ruby:2.3` image. but with latest ubuntu saw same troubles.
this article explains pretty straight forward how to use unicorn with nginx.
everything seems to be working if i start it from bash like this
`(cd /app && bundle exec unicorn -c /app/config/unicorn.rb -E uat -D)`

but i see errors if start it s as service
`service unicorn_appname start`

the error is:
`bundler: command not found: unicorn`

after i did some investigation i've realized that the issue is most probably in env variables because service essentially tries to execute my command with `su - root -c` prefix:

`su - root -c " cd /app && bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E uat -D"`

this command produces same error.

**though i am logged in as root in my bash as well**

after googling for a while i found partial solution - set PATH env variable like this:

`su - root -c "PATH=\"$(ruby -e 'print Gem.default_dir')/bin:$PATH\" && cd /app && bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E uat -D"`

but now i see `Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sources`.

and `rake --version` returns `rake, version 12.0.0`. Meanwhile `su - root -c "rake --version"` returns `rake, version 10.4.2`

`which rake` returns `/usr/local/bundle/bin/rake`, meanwhile `su - root -c "which rake"` returns `/usr/local/bin/rake`

**so my guess is that service tries to use wrong path for rake.**

**how do i change default rake path?** or any other suggestion where to dig into?

**---------------- UPDATE - kinda solution ---------------------**

i think i found the reason of all my issues with bundler in docker. looks like all env variables for bundler are set in shell startup part. thus they are not there if i run it as sudo `su - appuser -c "...cmd..."`

so i've tested it by running `printenv` right in bash. and another one like this `sudo su - appuser -c "printenv"`. - found big difference.

since i was building docker i've set them through docker file, but it also works if just export them.

```
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/bundle/gems/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV RUBYGEMS_VERSION=3.0.3
ENV RUBY_VERSION=2.3.8
ENV GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/usr/local/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1
ENV RUBY_MAJOR=2.3
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=/usr/local/bundle
```

i also did

```
RUN bundle config app_config /usr/local/bundle && bundle config path /usr/local/bundle
```

and since the right way is to not use root for web app i rebuild everything in docker file so it creates and uses separate user (but this part i guess is optional):

```
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser
....
#installing sudo
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
....
# gives sudo to new user
RUN echo "appuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/appuser && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/appuser
....
#don't forget to give rights to your folder for new user like this:
#RUN sudo chown -R appuser:appuser /usr/local
....
#utilize new user
USER appuser
#bundle install and rest stuff is here
....
```

hope my update save someone time